# Fuse Fabric deployment error | java.lang.Exception: Can not resolve feature

Tags: deployment, soa, esb, fuseesb, fusefabric

i am trying to deploy to Fuse Fabric. The application is built using Spring, Camel, CXF, WS-security, drools and Guvnor.

i was able to deploy the application to Karaf container, but when i deploy the same in Fabric  using the FAB deployment. it is throwing the below error stack.

```
java.lang.Exception: Can not resolve feature:
 Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   package:(&(package=org.ops4j.pax.exam.options)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
      Apache Aries Unit Test Support
   package:(&(package=org.apache.aries.mocks)(version>=0.3.0))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=org.ops4j.pax.exam)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
      Apache Aries Unit Test Support
   package:(&(package=javax.xml.namespace)(version>=5.0.0.2)(version<=5.0.0.2))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=org.apache.aries.unittest.fixture)(version>=0.4.0))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=org.apache.aries.unittest.mocks.annotations)(version>=0.3.0))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=org.apache.aries.itest)(version>=0.4.0))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=javax.xml.soap)(version>=5.0.0.2)(version<=5.0.0.2))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=org.junit))
      Apache Aries Unit Test Support
   package:(&(package=org.apache.aries.unittest.mocks)(version>=0.3.0))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=org.apache.aries.unittest.junit)(version>=0.3.0))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=javax.persistence)(version>=5.0.0.2)(version<=5.0.0.2))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
   package:(&(package=junit.framework))
      Apache Aries Unit Test Support
   package:(&(package=org.objectweb.asm)(version>=3.3.1)(version<=3.3.1))
      com.eissDemo.ServiceV2
```

Firstly, The above error  is asking me to include the Junit and mock related frameworks in the Fabric container, which is not required!? these frameworks are added with the "test" scope in the maven.

Secondly, the dependency "aries" is not being used in the project directly. It is used by the camel-cxf framework. But still it is asking the "aries" jars to be mentioned in the dependency. The FAB deployment should take care of these 3rd party dependencies or it defeats the purpose of using it!!

Third, the soap and namespace dependency are present in the maven dependency with the request version. still it is complaining!

i have the following features installed in the fabric

```
cxf
camel-xstream
camel-jaxb
camel-spring
camel-jms
camel-blueprint
spring
camel-core
fabric-camel
camel-spring-javaconfig
war
```

and the following maven features URLS

```
mvn:org.apache.servicemix.nmr/apache-servicemix-nmr/1.6.0.redhat-60024/xml/features
mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/2.6.0.redhat-60024/xml/features
mvn:org.jboss.fuse/jboss-fuse/6.0.0.redhat-024/xml/features
mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.10.0.redhat-60024/xml/features
```

and the application is used as the fab

```
mvn:com.xxxx/ServiceV2/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

can anyone tell me if i am using enough features or i need more, if so what all needs to be included? why do i need to include the testing frameworks in the fabric? or how do i avoid them being deployed in the fuse fabric?

Comment: What is FAB deployment?

Comment: Why are your test dependencies going into this bundle / feature? Can you check that such things are marked as `test` in your pom? Or can you put all the tests and test dependencies into a separate integration tests module...